# 'start on runlevel' command not working

Tags: boot, command-line, python, upstart, services

I have a `.py` script which I want to run at startup.

I wrote this code in a file named `test1.conf` and kept in `/etc/init`

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

python /home/partho/Documents/py/test/x.py
```

The command in the 3rd line is a valid command (tested).
This command is not running at startup, I am sure because a window should be shown by running the command, which I don't see.

What's going wrong?

Comment: By 'startup', do you mean before-user-login (boot) or after-user-login (session start)? Boot processes must run headless - displays are not available until after login. In either case, consider revising your script to use modern systemd targets instead of runlevels from two init generations ago.

Comment: I meant after login. By the way, I solved in another way.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to check that your conf file has any syntactical error or not by,typing cmd on terminal `init-checkconf /etc/init/<yourfile>.conf`
if it show `File /etc/init/<yourfile>.conf: syntax ok` then there is no syntactical error.
and write`exec python /home/partho/Documents/py/test/x.py` instead only giving cmd and check it.